# How to deliberately fail a network request in a Cypress test

Tags: cypress

We have added a new feature to our app for offline continuity, and I need the API requests not to return a value. There are a lot of tests and waiting for a disconnected API is not practical.

How can I simulate a disconnected network?

This is what I have so far, but it's not working

```js
cy.intercept({
  'GET',
  '**/api/**/*'
}, (req) => {
  throw 'Network failure'
})
.as('failed')

cy.visit('/')

cy.wait('@failed')

cy.get('[data-cy="Error message"]')
  .should('be.visible')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intercept command has an option `forceNetworkError` for this scenario

**Blanket fail for all requests**

```js
cy.intercept('**/api/**/*', { forceNetworkError: true })
  .as('failed')

cy.wait('@failed').should('have.property', 'error')
```

**Selective request failure**

Alternatively, you can `destroy()` the request selectively

```js
cy.intercept('**/api/**/*', (req) => {
  if (mustDestroy(req)) {
    req.destroy()
  }

  function mustDestroy(req) {
    return req.query.includes('something')  // destroy certain requests
  }
})
```

**Specific status code failures**

If the app responds differently for some status codes,

```js
cy.intercept('**/api/**/*', { statusCode: 500 })
  .as('failed')

cy.wait('@failed')
cy.contains('There was an error completing your request')
```